# Change the style of image with easySlider1.5.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use easySlider1.5.js and when I chose the attribute auto and continue the image run from right to left but I want the image run from left to right and don't back to the first image. So what should i do?....Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by changing `"next"` to `"prev"` at following place in easySlider1.5.js file, as:

```
if(options.auto){;
            timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                animate("prev",false);
            },options.pause);
        };
```

and use, `auto:true,continuous:true` in `defaults` variable.

Comment: Thank for your kindly reply but now I can fix it